# Re-projecting shapefiles (with different projections) to the projection of a specified shapefile: Error 000628

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcmap, idle, error-000628

I am trying to write a script to make a tool that will run in Arcmap 10.7.1.

I have a file with multiple different shapefiles with multiple different projections. Basically, it has to take the spatial reference of a specified shapefile and reproject it to all the others. When I run the script (hard-coding the 'arcpy.GetParameterAsText()' variables to test the functionality of the script), I get `ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter out_coor_system.`. How can I get around that and make the script functional?

Here is the code I have:

```
#Import modules
import arcpy, os

#Set workspace directory
from arcpy import env

#Define workspace
inWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
env.workspace = inWorkspace
env.overwriteOutput = True

#Define local shape file to reproject to
targetFeature = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#Describe the input feature class
inFc = arcpy.Describe(targetFeature)

#Define the spatial reference of the input feature class
sRef = inFc.spatialReference.name

#List the feature classes in the workspace
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()


#Reproject all the feature classes:
for fc in fcList:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    if desc.spatialReference.name != sRef:
        print "Projection of " + str(fc) + " is " + desc.spatialReference.name + ", so re-defining projection now:"
        newFc = arcpy.Project_management(fc, desc.name + "_projected", sRef)
        arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())
        newFc = arcpy.Describe(newFc)
        print str(fc) + " has been reprojected to " + str(newFc.spatialReference.name)
```

I'm trying to add the "_projected" to the original file name, to signify that it has been reprojected. Also, I'm using IDLE as my IDE.

Comment: Something off topic that may help is string.format() so the first line printed in your loop would look like 'Projection of {0} is {1}, so re-defining projection now:'.format(fc,desc.spatialReference.name) it's a little bit easier to read and you don't need to str(variable) to insert it in, python does the hard work for you; also with string.format() you can specify the number of decimal places in the output, reuse a single parameter or even use parameters out of order (like '{0} {2} {1}') read more https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `arcpy.Project_management()` you are passing the name of the spatial reference, not the spatial reference itself.  Although the documentation for the `out_coor_system` parameter states

> Valid values are a Spatial Reference object, a file with a .prj extension, or a string representation of a coordinate system.

I'm not sure if the name of a spatial reference system qualifies as "a string representation of a coordinate system".

So change this line:

```
sRef = inFc.spatialReference.name
```

to this:

```
sRef = inFc.spatialReference
```

This would also require you to change:

```
    if desc.spatialReference.name != sRef:
```

to this:

```
    if desc.spatialReference.name != sRef.name:
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I made all of those changes. After running the new code, however, I am getting the ```ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Create output feature class failed, failed to execute(Project).``` Can you see something else that might cause that exception to be raised? **Code is the same as my original entry, just with those changes.**

Comment: Instead of `desc.name + "_projected"`, try `fc + "_projected"`. I don't think the `Describe()` for a feature class includes a `name` property.  (If your `fc` is a shapefile, you'll need to cater for the ".shp" in its name by removing it and then adding it at the end).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that in order to get the original code to work, you have to change the order of the output feature class notation.

Instead of:
`newFc = arcpy.Project_management(fc, desc.name + "_projected", sRef)`

You must use this instead:
`newFc = arcpy.Project_management(fc, "projected_" + fc, sRef)`

It then runs.